# Stretch image in imageView in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview, xamarin.android

I am developing an application for Android that displays pictures of animals in ImageView in PageViewer. On most of the phones, everything seems fine. However, on my S7 (display resolution higher than the resolution of the picture), I can't get the picture to stretch to expand the device width.

The imageView also has a Xamarin photoView attacher attached to it, however I don't think it has any effect. I tried to remove it and it's still the same.

I already tried android:adjustViewBounds and all android:scaleType and unfortunately it didn't help.

Here is my xml code:
Part of the activity xml:

```
<fieldguideapp.droid.MyViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pagerAnimalProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

PagerLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/imgPagerLayoutImageView" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutImgPagerImageDesc"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <TextView
            android:text="Image desc"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textColor="#FF000000"
            android:id="@+id/txtImgPagerImageDescription"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linLayoutImgPagerIndicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/txtImgPagerImageDescription" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Image credit"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textColor="#FF000000"
            android:id="@+id/txtImgPagerImageCredit"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/linLayoutImgPagerIndicator" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Part of code that changes the height of the pager:

```
// To specify the height of the pager, select the highest child
protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
    {
        View child = GetChildAt(i);
        child.Measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified));
        int h = child.MeasuredHeight;
        if (h > height) height = h;
    }
    if (Resources.Configuration.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Portrait)
    {
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
    }
    base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

EDIT: Here is what I get:
[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape]

I would appreciate any kind of help or advice. Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot with your problem? Also, have you tried fitXY and centerCrop in the scaleType?

Comment: @jonathanrz Yes, I tried fitXY and centerCrop. Unfortunately, didn't help me!

Comment: scaleType=fitXY should do what you need. I'm not pretty sure what adjustViewBounds do, can you put fitXY and remove the adjustViewBounds for testing?

Comment: @jonathanrz I tried to remove adjustViewBounds with both centerCrop and fitXY and it's still the same. Looks like changing the scaleType has no effect, which is really weird :(

Comment: How you are setting the image in the View?

Comment: @jonathanrz I create a Bitmap from byte[] using BitmapFactory and then use function imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

Comment: Try to add imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP) after setting the image bitmap.

Comment: @jonathanrz Sorry for not replying for a long time. I tried setting scaleType after the image and it actually does have some affect. However, it does not do what I want. See [link](https://postimg.org/image/cj1u8g98n/) I want the imageView to strech vertically and keep aspect ration of the image. Is it possible?

Comment: I believe that what you need is ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE

Comment: @jonathanrz Thanks, but that one doesn't help. It does the same thing as if I didn't set anything. (See original screenshot) I think it has something to do with the ViewPager and the height on the pager.

Comment: Hi did you fixed this ?
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        CarouselResponse.PromotionCarousel carousel = mList.get(position);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(container.getContext().getApplicationContext());
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
I used this code for pagerAdapter but still same as yours

Comment: @AngelJanniee Look at my answer below. I know it isn't optimal, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually resized the picture manually using `Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap()` method to fit the screen dimensions and then set it using `ImageView.SetImageDrawable()` and it works perfectly. I need to call `GC.Collect()` before and after in order to avoid OutOfMemoryException.

Although this isn't ideal, it works.